# (list index out of range)Where have i clucked up?

Tags: python

What am I missing? It's probably something obvious, but I haven't dealt with python in a while.

```
import random

def main():

        userlist = generateList()
        value = userInput()
        lessThan(userlist,value)

def generateList():

    randomlist = []
    for i in range(0,40):
        num = random.randint(1,100)
        randomlist.append(num)

    print('Your list is:' )
    print(randomlist)
    return randomlist

def userInput():

    selection = -1
    while 0 > selection > 100:
         selection = input('Please select a value between 1 and 100: ')
    return selection

def lessThan(randomlist,selection):

    for i in range(len(randomlist)):
        if randomlist[i] <= selection:
            continue
        else:
           randomlist.pop(i)

    randomlist.sort()
    print('Values in your list bigger than' + selection + 'are: ')
    print(randomlist)
    return randomlist

main()
```

line 30, in lessThan
if randomlist[i] <= selection:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You're removing elements from the list while you're iterating over the range of its original length.

Comment: Don't pop list items in the loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: Also, in 
`print('Values in your list bigger than' + selection + 'are: ')`

You can't concatenate string with integer type of value. Instead of +, use a comma(,).